Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. NextJS and Auth 5 Credentials Login
I keep on getting this error when setting up my credentials login using google One-Tap. I have tried a couple of first-thought fixes(that didn't work)
Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
at Proxy.callable (file:///Users/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX.org/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/dist/src/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/request-cookies.ts:22:10)
at signIn (turbopack://[project]/node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:47:18)
45 |     const cookieJar = await cookies();
46 |     for (const c of res?.cookies ?? [])

47 |         cookieJar.set(c.name, c.value, c.options);
|                  ^
48 |     const responseUrl = res instanceof Response ? res.headers.get("Location") : res.redirect;
49 |     // NOTE: if for some unexpected reason the responseUrl is not set,
50 |     // we redirect to the original url

//HERE IS MY CODE
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

 
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth  } = NextAuth({
  // trustHost: true,
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET ?? "",
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
      // allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true
    }),
    Credentials({
      name: "google-one-tap",
      id: "google-one-tap",
      credentials: {
        credential: { type : "text" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        "use server"
        const session = await auth()
        if (session) {
          console.log('session already dey', session)
          throw new Error("Session already exists")
        }
        const { credential } = credentials ?? {}
        if (credentials === null) return null;        
        // console.log('credential', credential)
        const response = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=" + credential)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log('data', data)

        if (data.email_verified) {
          return {
            id: data.sub,
            email: data.email,
            name: data.name,
            image: data.picture
          }
        }

        return null
      }
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
      async jwt({ token, user }) {
        "use server"
        if (user) {
          token.id = user.id
        }
        return token
      }
  },
})

I keep on getting this error when setting up my credentials login using google One-Tap. I have tried a couple of first-thought fixes(that did'nt work)
